# Docusign - eNotary in Sandbox

Tags: docusignapi, sandbox, notary

I am using the sandbox account and trying to setup an eNotary Profile.  Being that its a sandbox area, I would assume that I don't need a valid notary ID to create one.

Can someone help me setup a Notary Profile on my sandbox account?

**QA Question Newly Added:** Will ALL test users have to go through this same process? or is it just the main account needs it setup.  Reason being, we have a client that will be using the system.  For our teams, and their teams, we will need accounts to test this.

**Added Image**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about IDV which is a special kind of recipient authentication that require them to use an ID before they can sign a document.
This feature is not available in the sandbox normally because there's cost associated with each transaction.
We may be able to assist you on a case-by-case basis if you have a legitimate need to test this functionality in the developer sandbox.
see https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/recipient-authentication for more information about recipient authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do understand the difference in flow and how it changes everything.  I also have all the api code wired up to handle the notary scenario (which was not easy to figure out).  I now get an error, that the account is not a notary.

Comment: yes, you need to ask to enable it for your account. once you open a support ticket - we'll take care of it for you.

Comment: when this is fixed - please mark this question as answered. thanks!

Comment: any idea how to open a support ticket for a sandbox account?  I can't find it on the site.  It wants me to login using a normal account.

Comment: send me an email to inbar.gazit@docusign.com with your sandbox accounts details and I'll help you out

Comment: Sent the email.  Thanks for your help

Comment: We got the api to send the email, which is way farther than I was.  Now I just need to add the profile to the account, so I can go through eNotary flow.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up eNotary requires some back-end switches to be flipped on your account. Please open a [Support Case](https://support.docusign.com) requesting that be enabled and provide your Demo account ID.

Comment: I was online with their chat and they told me to come here.  So I will look into opening a support case and update results here.