# Recipient roles in template creation

Tags: docusignapi

How can I disable the following recipient roles

- Receives a copy
- Signs with notary

** [image]I have already disabled the other recipient roles

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove Carbon Copy (CC), it will always be there.

Notary can be removed only be removing the Notary functionality. This should be in the Settings/Admin section of your web app.

Comment: Still unable to find it. Any link or screenshot will be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632569/docusign-enotary-in-sandbox

Comment: Please go to the top-right of the screen and choose "My Preferences"

Comment: Find "Electronic Notary Public" in there